# object cannot support method .value in HTA on VDI

Tags: html, vba, hta

In HTA application in ***body*** section there is a filed:

```
<input type="text" name="txtName" size="60">
```

And in ***script*** section there is:

```
Set ADSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set CurrentUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & ADSysInfo.UserName)
myName  = CurrentUser.givenName & " " & CurrentUser.sn
txtName.Value = myName

If Len(txtName.Value) > 0 then
(...)
End If
```

Problem is in **if** line. Error:

> Object cannot support that method: 'txtName.Value'

Thing is that that problem is only on Virtual Digital Image of Windows 7. When I launch that script on local machine (Windows 7) no errors occur. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was because body section was duplicated by accidentally copy-paste a piece of code.